# Android ListView in Tab shows only one line

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with the size of a ListView within a tab.

I think it's something simple, but I can not find the solution alone.

The activity is the same as the default, except for the TextView that was changed with the ListView.

I use an ArrayAdapter with a dummy list of three items ("P1", "P2", "P3").

All dimensions are set to "match_parent" or "wrap_content"

What I get is this: I see only "P1" instead of the whole list, with a little scrollbar that allow to scroll between the values. 
What I would like to see is the entire list.

[screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OF9z4.png)

Can someone help me?

*main activity layout*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="it.danapps.mycommunity.ChooseTags">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/container_choose_tags"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

*fragment*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="it.danapps.mycommunity.ChooseTags$PlaceholderFragment">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chooseTagListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
```

**EDIT**
1. Forcing the height to 300dp I see the list. But how can I do it automatically to Android, adapting to the screen?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="it.danapps.mycommunity.ChooseTags$PlaceholderFragment">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chooseTagListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
     />
```

[image: ListView with 300dp height]

Comment: Try to change  android:layout_height for both ListView and NestedScrollView to match_parent.

Comment: I tried, but it does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

If you TextViews are being set to "match_parent" that would be your issue. Make sure your TextViews are using either a set height or using "wrap_content". Otherwise your TextView will try to fill the height of the scrollview its placed in which is why you are only seeing the first one.

Comment: Yes, forcing the height to 300dp I see the list. But how can I do it automatically to Android, adapting to the screen?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? If you need each cell in the scrollview to be the height of the screen you can set the layout params of the child params to the screen height programmatically. If you need TextViews to be just as tall as required to fit the text it contains you can use "wrap_content"

Comment: I would like to see the entire list on screen: see all the elements up to the screen availability (the rest will be displayed using the scroll bar). Try to explain me better: in the screen I have space to see the 3 elements, but if I use "Match_parent" or "fill_content" I only see one; Forcing the height to dp (eg 300), I see the 3 elements correctly. Update the post by also putting this screenshot

Comment: Ok, I see you are using 300dp for the ListView height. That isnt correct. the ListView can be "match_parent". But the TextView child, those pieces of text being added to the scrolling ListView, need to have their height set to "wrap_content" or some desired height in dp. So to reiterate, the ListViews height should be "match_parent" which will give you the available height of the screen. And the child views (the TextViews containing P1, etc) need to have a set height or "wrap_content"